# Matlab GUI using getappdata and setappdata

Tags: user-interface, matlab

Basically what I want to do is have one gui that is just a title and a push button that calls uigetfile(), and once the user selects an image, the gui closes, and opens a new gui that contains the image, functions applied to the image, and information about the image. I have made all the code for everything, I just can't figure out how to use setappdata and getappdata so that the new gui opens with everything I want.

Comment: These links were *easily* found with Google: [Ways to Manage Data in a Programmatic GUI](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/creating_guis/f13-998352.html) and [Sharing Data with Application Data](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/creating_guis/f13-998449.html#f13-1000011). A better question is why you need to do this at all. When the first GUI gets the image file, simply pass that as an argument to the function that creates the second GUI, where it can be loaded and displayed. It's not clear exactly what you're doing or what problem you are having. More details are needed.

Answer (score -3):

[Mathworks](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/getappdata.html) website contains detailed information for most of matlabs functions.

Comment: The mathworks description for those functions do not explain how to use them :(